# Moving a div above or after another div, depending on space available?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm working on a project that uses jQuery and has been moving pages over to Bootstrap. Below is a mockup of a typical Bootstrap generated page, showing the actual UI as-is (which works great) plus a sample error message (to be coded).

My question is, how to implement the containers for the error messages, since they (1) are nested objects and (2) move `above <---> right` of the main control depending on width available. I'm not sure what's best, given that combination.

## Desired effect

*(Note I'm being deliberately vague about terms like "width" and "size", because they could be the width and size of **any suitable element** - the screen, the containing table, the element - and in raw pixels or bootstrap sizes (sm/md/lg/xl). Whatever works easiest.)*

The controls are defined with a max width. In effect they are fixed size on all but the smallest screens. The error container should be on top of the control, when the available width is below "some specified size", but when the width gets "larger" than some specified size, the error container moves to the right of the control as shown. The error container has variable width and takes up the full remaining width up to the right of the table.

I don't mind if this is done using bootstrap or pure CSS (using ::before/after). But it happens for all error containers on a page at the same time.

Vertical alignment for the right-side position is still unsettled. Assume center aligned if it matters.

## Coding considerations

- I'm thinking of the error container being a `div` rather than nesting each row's controls + error container as a new sub-table. Mainly because I don't know how to get the right effect with nested elements, or how bootstrap columns work in nested tables. Also it seems overkill - I just want one `div` to move, and probably don't need sub-tables to achieve that. But if nesting is easiest, its fine.
- If controls have id = `[control_01_id]` ... `[control_99_id]`, all with class `control`, the error containers could have id = `[control_01_id]_errmsg` ... `[control_99_id]_errmsg`, all with class `control_errmsg`.
- Circularity due to resizing shouldn't be an issue. I can always trigger moving to the top on width < say 750 but only trigger moving to the right on width > say 800, if an issue.
- I'd really like to avoid re-detecting resize events myself; if I can use bootstrap -pull/-push, or pure CSS (::before/after??), or if bootstrap provides a hook to detect resize events which I can use to detect the size of the main table or the error containers, and I just reparent the error containers with jQuery, that's much preferred.
- I could add empty `<span id="[control_id]_errmsg_above"></span>` and `<span id="[control_id]_errmsg_side"></span>` tags above and to the right of each control, so that the actual error container just gets given a new parent depending on size. That helps if the easiest way is to hook resize events, check width, and use jQuery to reparent the error containers.
- Browser compatibility is probably important if I'm not just using jQuery/Bootstrap, but relying on modern CSS/HTML features. If I'm using a library, it's less of a problem. So I haven't looked into this for now.

Any help appreciated!

## Screenshots and HTML

## Narrow layout:

[image]

## Wide layout:

[image]

## HTML (before adding error containers)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="DialogPipe" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="DialogPipeLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="DialogPipeLabel">Edit pipe</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="frm_DialogPipe">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
              <colgroup>
                <col class="col-md-3" />
                <col class="col-md-9" />
              </colgroup>
              <tbody>
                <tr id="row_pipe.bandwidth">
                  <td>
                    <div class="control-label" id="control_label_pipe.bandwidth">
                      <a id="help_for_pipe.bandwidth" href="#" class="showhelp"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
                      <b>Bandwidth</b>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control " size="50" id="pipe.bandwidth">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="row_pipe.bandwidthMetric">
                  <td>
                    <div class="control-label" id="control_label_pipe.bandwidthMetric">
                      <i class="fa fa-info-circle text-muted"></i>
                      <b>Bandwidth Metric</b>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <select id="pipe.bandwidthMetric" class="selectpicker" data-width="334px"></select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_DialogPipe_save">Save <i id="btn_DialogPipe_save_progress" class=""></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: read up on "responsive html" perhaps

Comment: https://every-layout.dev/layouts/stack/